# how do we read the "contents" of a `<script>` tag?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications

I like the JSONP where we can get info cross-domainly however, what if some services do not support JSONP (and hence do not provide a callback?)

I need a solution to this problem.

I'm thinking if we have a tag like this `<script id="s1" source="http://other.com/asd"></script>` how do we go about extracting the "contents" of `s1` ?

Initially I'd thought `s1.innerHTML` would do the trick but well.. apparently it doesn't do the trick.

I'm wondering if anyone has any "hacks" that they would love to share.

**HACKS ARE WELCOMED**

Comment: What script, specifically, are you trying to include?

Comment: @Casey Hope . I want to have the ability to do so in times of need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a security feature. In the absence of any major security flaws, there's no way to perform a cross-site request without the cooperation of the site you're making the request to.

Comment: @Pacerier: Browser vendors have worked hard to make that kind of thing impossible. The security model is called [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and thankfully, it works pretty well.